# Wrap a long, multiline, unwieldy equation in case environment

Tags: equations, cases, split

This is ugly:

[image]

But, the equation is hard to reduce without making convoluted substitutions. I have ideas to improve, but don't know how:

- Remove spacing after the commas
- Pad between the lines containing conditions
- It would be nice if the equation number (1) was to the right, but I don't believe there's any way it could fit.

Any other suggestions?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        & E^{G4}_{f}[\textbf{k}] = \\
        & \begin{cases}
            \min\Big \{ \max \{ E^G_{f|H}[\textbf{k}] + (E^G_{f'|H}[\textbf{k}] - E^G_{f',min}[\textbf{k}]), & E^G_{f,min}[\textbf{k}] \}, E^G_{f,max}[\textbf{k}] \Big \} \\ & \text{for } E^G_{f'|H}[\textbf{k}] < E^G_{f',min}[\textbf{k}]\\
            \min\Big \{ \max \{ E^G_{f|H}[\textbf{k}] + (E^G_{f'|H}[\textbf{k}] - E^G_{f',max}[\textbf{k}]), & E^G_{f,min}[\textbf{k}] \}, E^G_{f,max}[\textbf{k}] \Big \} \\ & \text{for } E^G_{f'|H}[\textbf{k}] > E^G_{f',max}[\textbf{k}]\\
            \min\Big \{ \max \{ E^G_{f|H}[\textbf{k}], E^G_{f,min}[\textbf{k}] \}, E^G_{f,max}[\textbf{k}] \Big \} & \\ & \text{otherwise}
        \end{cases}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the overall constraints imposed by the document class and the font size, there's nothing "huge" that can be done. However, there are a few smaller aspects of the equation that can be changed. I suggest (a) using a `dcases` environment instead of the current `cases` environment, (b) placing the "for ..." conditions for cases 1 and 2 on separate lines, (c) using upright letters for "min" and "max" in the subscript terms, (d) increasing the sizes of the inner curly braces and round parentheses to `\big`, (e) providing a bit more vertical whitespace after the first two "for ..." lines, and (f) using an `align` environment instead of an `equation` environment, so that the equation number is placed at the height of the middle `\min` term.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'dcases' env.
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E} % expectations operator
\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of textblock
\bigskip\noindent
Before:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        & E^{G4}_{f}[\textbf{k}] = \\
        & \begin{cases}
            \min\Big \{ \max \{ E^G_{f|H}[\textbf{k}] + (E^G_{f'|H}[\textbf{k}] - E^G_{f',min}[\textbf{k}]), & E^G_{f,min}[\textbf{k}] \}, E^G_{f,max}[\textbf{k}] \Big \} \\ & \text{for } E^G_{f'|H}[\textbf{k}] < E^G_{f',min}[\textbf{k}]\\
            \min\Big \{ \max \{ E^G_{f|H}[\textbf{k}] + (E^G_{f'|H}[\textbf{k}] - E^G_{f',max}[\textbf{k}]), & E^G_{f,min}[\textbf{k}] \}, E^G_{f,max}[\textbf{k}] \Big \} \\ & \text{for } E^G_{f'|H}[\textbf{k}] > E^G_{f',max}[\textbf{k}]\\
            \min\Big \{ \max \{ E^G_{f|H}[\textbf{k}], E^G_{f,min}[\textbf{k}] \}, E^G_{f,max}[\textbf{k}] \Big \} & \\ & \text{otherwise}
        \end{cases}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

\bigskip\noindent
After:
\begin{align}
& E^{G4}_{f}[\textbf{k}] = \notag \\
& \begin{dcases}
   \min\Bigl\{ \max \bigl\{ E^G_{f\mid H}[\textbf{k}] + \bigl(E^G_{f'\mid H}[\textbf{k}] - E^G_{f',\min}[\textbf{k}]\bigr), 
   E^G_{f,\min}[\textbf{k}] \bigr\}, 
   E^G_{f,\max}[\textbf{k}] \Bigr\} \\ 
   \qquad\text{for $E^G_{f'\mid H}[\textbf{k}] < E^G_{f',\min}[\textbf{k}]$}\\[1ex]
   \min\Bigl\{ \max \bigl\{ E^G_{f\mid H}[\textbf{k}] + \bigl(E^G_{f'\mid H}[\textbf{k}] - E^G_{f',\max}[\textbf{k}]\bigr), 
   E^G_{f,\min}[\textbf{k}] \bigr\}, 
   E^G_{f,\max}[\textbf{k}] \Bigr\} \\ 
   \qquad\text{for $E^G_{f'\mid H}[\textbf{k}] > E^G_{f',\max}[\textbf{k}]$}\\[1ex]
   \min\Bigl\{ \max \bigl\{ E^G_{f\mid H}[\textbf{k}], E^G_{f,\min}[\textbf{k}] \bigr\}, 
   E^G_{f,\max}[\textbf{k}] \Bigr\} \quad\text{otherwise}
\end{dcases}
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

Comment: for the first example, the `amsmath` command `\raisetag` could be used to move the equation number up onto the last line, where there is space.  i'd try `\raisetag{1\baselineskip}` to start.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks, that's a really good suggestion. I didn't modify the "before" code in order to make the changes contained in the "after" block more readily apparent.

Comment: This worked well, thanks. I moved "otherwise" to it's own line as well, for consistency, and used \hspace to shift the condition lines further to the right. Also, E is a function (energy at hour k) in this case, not an operator.

Comment: @LShaver - Glad to know my answer was useful. And, thanks for cluing me in as to what "E" stands for. I'll update the answer accordingly.